# Problemas al cerrar SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview

Tengo algunos problemas con cerrar mi `SearchView`

**El primero:** **SOLUCIONADO**

Cuando busco en mi `listview` y entro en la `Activity` que encuentra, al volver atrás mi `SearchView` sigue abierta ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se cierre automáticamente?

**El segundo:** **SOLUCIONADO**

Para abrir mi `SearchView` hago click sobre el icono (lupa) que tengo en `menu/menu_buscar` con ID `action_search` ¿Cómo puedo hacer que para qué cuando este abierta y haga click se cierre?

**Y por último**: **SOLUCIONADO** he creado este código para poder cerrar mi `SearchView` desde el botón *atrás* del móvil, pero cómo puedo hacer para que cuando este cerrada su función sea la que es por defecto, ir atrás en mi `Activity`

Código para cerrar la `SearchView` haciendo click en el botón *atrás* del móvil

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    searchView.closeSearch();
}
```

Código para las dos primeras cuestiones:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat_shishas);
    icon_cat_shi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_cat_shi);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    imagenes = new ArrayList();
    for (Integer pos : new int[]{
            R.drawable.icon_1,
            R.drawable.icon_2,
    }) {
        imagenes.add(pos);
    }
    final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shi);

    titulo = new ArrayList();
    for (String tit : getResources().getStringArray(R.array.as1)) {
        titulo.add(tit);
    }

    adapter = new IndexAdapter(this, new int[]{0, 1});
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {

            switch ((Integer) adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
                case 0:
                    Intent aln = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Assq.class);
                    startActivity(aln);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent caer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Aassa.class);
                    startActivity(caer);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList();
                for (String item : titulo) {
                    if (item.contains(newText))
                        lstFound.add(item);
                }

                String[] subTitulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);
                adapter.set(subTitulo);
            } else {
                adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

La primera y última cuestión han quedado solucionadas, me falta la segunda.
Cuando hago click en `action_search` se abre la `SearchView` hasta ahí todo OK, pero quiero que cuando este abierta su función sea cerrar la `SearchView` cómo podría hacerlo?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    return true;
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 3:** para @StefanNolde

He creado una nueva clase llamada `MyMSView`

```
import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView;


public class MyMSView extends MaterialSearchView {

//////////// creo campo MenuItem

    MenuItem mMenuItem;

//////////////// creo el constructor que me pide Android Studio

    public MyMSView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        this.mMenuItem = menuItem;
        mMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (isSearchOpen()){
                    closeSearch();
                } else {
                    showSearch();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`Activity`

```
import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView;
import otrointento.dos.MyMSView;

public class Cat_shishas extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyMSView searchView;
    IndexAdapter adapter;
    ImageView icon_cat_shi;

    ArrayList<String> titulo;
    ArrayList<Integer> imagenes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat_shishas);
        icon_cat_shi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_cat_shi);
        imagenes = new ArrayList();
        for (Integer pos : new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        }){ imagenes.add(pos); }
        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shi);

        titulo =new ArrayList();
        for (String tit : getResources().getStringArray(shishas)){
            titulo.add(tit);
        }
        adapter = new IndexAdapter(this, new int[]{0, 1});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch ((Integer)adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent alas = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Clase1.class);
                        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView.closeSearch();
                        startActivity(alas);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent cssa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Clase2.class);
                        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView.closeSearch();
                        startActivity(cssa);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        searchView = (MyMSView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList();
                    for (String item : titulo) {
                        if (item.contains(newText))
                            lstFound.add(item);
                    }

                    String[] subTitulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);
                    adapter.set(subTitulo);
                } else {
                    //if search text is null
                    //return default
                    adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return true;
    }
```

`Layout:`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_cat_shishas">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="184dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center">

            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:searchBackground="@drawable/contorno_design"
                app:searchSuggestionBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:searchCloseIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close_inverted"
                app:searchBackIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back_inverted"
                app:searchSuggestionIcon="@drawable/ic_suggestion"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:elevation="2dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_shi"
                android:id="@+id/icon_cat_shi"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                />

            <View
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/linea1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="380dp" />

            <View
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/linea2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_width="380dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f7f7f7"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/cat_shi_vertical">

            <View
                android:background="@drawable/degradado"
                android:id="@+id/separador1"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listview_shi"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
                android:layout_height="1650dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Como bien me avisaste recibo `ClassCastException`

`Logcat`

```
02-09 23:26:08.360 14718-14718/otrointento.dos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: otrointento.dos, PID: 14718
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{otrointento.dos/otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_shishas}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView cannot be cast to otrointento.dos.MyMSView
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView cannot be cast to otrointento.dos.MyMSView
                                                                      at otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_shishas.onCreate(Cat_shishas.java:83)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:**

`logcast`

```
02-10 02:10:42.622 16441-16441/otrointento.dos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: otrointento.dos, PID: 16441
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{otrointento.dos/otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_shishas}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class otrointento.dos.MyMSView
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class otrointento.dos.MyMSView
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class otrointento.dos.MyMSView
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                      at otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_shishas.onCreate(Cat_shishas.java:42)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**para caso 1**

para cerrar el searchView antes de partir a otras actividades:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {

        switch ((Integer) adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
            case 0:
                Intent aln = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Assq.class);
                if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView,closeSearch();
                startActivity(aln);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent caer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Aassa.class);
                if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView,closeSearch();
                startActivity(caer);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

**para caso 2**

en `onOptionsItemSelected`puedes diferenciar:

```
if (null!=searchView && searchView.isSearchOpen()){
    searchView.close();
    return true;
} else {
    // cosas que hacer para la busqueda
    return true;
}
```

Pero como el searchView te tapa el menu, tienes que modificar el listener en MaterialSearchView. Revisando el código fuente de `MaterialSearchView`, lo siguiente te debería solucionar lo que quieres hacer:

```
// vamos a hacer una subclase de MaterialSearchView:
public class MyMSView extends MaterialSearchView{

    public MyMSView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyMSView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyMSView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        this.mMenuItem = menuItem;
        mMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (isSearchOpen()){
                     closeSearch();
                } else {
                     showSearch();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

luego usas `MyMSView` en ves de `MaterialSearchView` en tu actividad.

**para caso 3**
cerrar en `onBackPressed()`

si te entiendo bien, quieres mantener la función original de `onBackPressed()`. Si quieres eso, no deberías olvidar en un @Override de tambien llamar la función original:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
        searchView.closeSearch();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

o si quieres hacer la una **o** la otra cosa, dependiente si el `searchView` esta abierto:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
        searchView.closeSearch();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**actualisación**

Tu delincuente se encuentra aquí:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView cannot be cast to otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_prueba$MyMSView
   at otrointento.dos.categorias.Cat_prueba.onCreate(Cat_prueba.java:188)
```

tu tienes que cambiar los casts:

```
searchView = (MaterialSearchView)
```

tiene que ser

```
searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

y searchView tiene que ser declarado como MyMSView. Una parte donde **no** tienes que cambiar al nombre de la nueva clase es:

```
new MyMSView.OnQueryTextListener()
```

eso **NO** funciona, tienes que seguir declarando `MaterialSearchView.OnClickListener()`, porque la clase interna sigue siendo lo mismo. Cuando uno hace una subclase, no se lleva todos los aspectos estáticos.
En general mientras corriges los errores, recuerda:

- La instancia (new Class()...) tiene que ser tu nueva clase.
- La variable deberías declarar como tu nueva clase
- el layout debe tener el `<tag>` de tu nueva clase
- en el contexto estático sigues usando `MaterialSearchView`, por ejemplo en nombres de clases internos

**actualisación 2**

```
import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView;
// aquí tienes que importar tu clase (si no es en el mismo paquete)

public class Cat_shishas extends AppCompatActivity {

    ///////////////// cambio MaterialSearchView searchView; por:
    // no. "Clase variable;" - eso es la declaracion.
    //MaterialSearchView MyMSView;
    MyMSView searchView;
    IndexAdapter adapter;
    ImageView icon_cat_shi;

    ArrayList<String> titulo;
    ArrayList<Integer> imagenes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat_shishas);
        icon_cat_shi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_cat_shi);
        imagenes = new ArrayList();
        for (Integer pos : new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        }) {
            imagenes.add(pos);
        }
        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shi);

        titulo = new ArrayList();
        for (String tit : getResources().getStringArray(shishas)) {
            titulo.add(tit);
        }
        adapter = new IndexAdapter(this, new int[]{0, 1});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch ((Integer) adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent alas = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Clase1.class);

/////////////////////// cambio searchView por MyMSView
// de nuevo no, el nombre de tu variable estaba bien, la clase tiene que ser la tuya

                        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView.closeSearch();
                        startActivity(alas);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent cssa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Clase2.class);

/////////////////////// cambio searchView por MyMSView
// y de nuevo véase arriba

                        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) searchView.closeSearch();
                        startActivity(cssa);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

// si eso aquí te da una ClassCastException, revisa tu layout 
        searchView = (MyMSView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

/////////////////////// cambio searchView por MyMSView        
// MaterialSearchView aqui esta bien, porque nos referímos a la clase interna de MaterialSearchView
        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

/////////////////////// cambio searchView por MyMSView
// idem
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList();
                    for (String item : titulo) {
                        if (item.contains(newText))
                            lstFound.add(item);
                    }

                    // usemos otro nombre de variable para mas claridad
                    // aun que diferenciemos entre this.titulo y titulo, así queda mas obvio
                    String[] subTitulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);
                    // de nuevo, quedemos con el mismo adapter.
                    adapter.set(subTitulo);
                } else {
                    //if search text is null
                    //return default
                    // y de nuevo ;)
                    adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Me da la impresión que haces mucho "monkey patching", usando código de ejemplos que en el fondo no entiendes bien. Te recomiendo de meterte un poco en los básicos, Java basico, conceptos de POO. Mira aqui:

[¡No temas a la POO!](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/jon/family/jos/oop_es/oop1.htm)

**actualisación 3**

tu problema es eso:

```
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:searchBackground="@drawable/contorno_design"
            app:searchSuggestionBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:searchCloseIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close_inverted"
            app:searchBackIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back_inverted"
            app:searchSuggestionIcon="@drawable/ic_suggestion"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="2dp" />
```

tiene que ser:

```
        <otrointento.dos.MyMSView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:searchBackground="@drawable/contorno_design"
            app:searchSuggestionBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:searchCloseIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close_inverted"
            app:searchBackIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back_inverted"
            app:searchSuggestionIcon="@drawable/ic_suggestion"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="2dp" />
```

**actualisación 4**

Faltaban los constructores en `MyMSView`. lo he actualizado arriba.

Comment: Tu haces una clase tal cual como en el código que te dejé, puedes hacerlo en un archivo propio o como clase interno, en el archivo de tu actividad (una inner class). Despues remplazas el `new MaterialSearchView...`con `new MyMSView...`. Consejo: crea la clase como describí, luego borras el import para `MaterialSearchView`, Asi Studio te muestra donde tienes que editar

Comment: Ah, si, los puntos estan en desorden. Lo editaré.

Comment: Tu nunca importaste tu clase, pero cambiaste el nombre de tu variable al nombre de la clase, eso no puede funcionar. Te lo voy a corregir.

Comment: Si no me equivoco el cambio que hay que hacer en `XML` es por el cambio que hicimos al añadir la nueva clase `MyMSView` por cierto, se sigue cerrando la aplicación, añado el logcat a la pregunta, gracias @StefanNolde !

Comment: Revisa si te funciona con MyMSView actualizado.

Comment: Ahora perfecto! Es posible que el icono de `action_search` cambie por otro cuando este abierta la `SearchView`? @StefanNolde

Comment: Es posible, no he revisado completamente lo que hace `MaterialSearchView`. Enfoqué en lo que quisiste implementar. Porque?

Comment: Porque quiero intentar hacer que se cambie el icono cuando este abierta, pero probaré yo a ver si lo consigo, sino, creo una pregunta nueva, gracias por toda tu ayuda @StefanNolde aprendo mucho contigo, eres de lo mejor que hay por aquí ayudando, y no es peloteo, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

1) En realidad lo que estas abriendo es el menú y no el SearchView, para detectar se esta abriendo el SearchView puedes agregar un Listener, obtienes la referencia del ImageView y cambias su visibilidad:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            icon_cat_shi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

2) para cerrarlo programaticamente en otra acción además de activar el botón "regreso" puedes implementar que cuando es abre otra Activity se cierre mediante:

```
 if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
 }
```